# Is it always possible to create a minimum depth tree where tree nodes are unique and have a 'choice'?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, graph-colorings

This is a somewhat long question thus sincere apologies beforehand. In a tree a node is a simple point. Now instead of a node let us consider a set of 'choice nodes' that have the following properties:

1. Each 'node' has a top side, bottom side, and a unique set of K distinct color pairs (vertical top-bottom pairs). Each color always pairs with exactly one other color (eg: red with pink, orange with yellow and so on).
2. Each 'node' can connect to another via an edge only b/w two same colors: edge b/w bottom of upper node and top of lower node (in a tree).
3. In any 'node' both colors of a pair cannot take part in connections. These connections are illegal.

[image]

Given a set of $C$ color pairs, each color pair occurring exactly $2k$ times in total: $k$ times as $C_{red}:C_{pink}$ and $k$ times as $C_{pink}:C_{red}$. Each node has $p$ color pairs (4 in example). Thus total number of Nodes given to us are $N = 2kC/p$

**Query 1:** Given any set of such nodes, can we always create a pair of trees $T_1$ and $T_2$ such that:

1. $Depth(T_1/T_2) \leq log_{p-1}N$? In other words, can we always create a pair of trees with smallest depth possible?
2. The root node in $T_1$ and $T_2$ have a set of 'complementary unconnected pair' i.e. if root of $T_1$ has $C_{red}:C_{pink}$ then root of $T_2$ has $C_{pink}:C_{red}$ such that neither pair is connected to their child nodes in the tree.

I believe the answer is yes, but I am struggling to formally prove it. If NO can someone explain why (with an explicit example if possible).

**Query 2:** Assuming answer is YES, what algo can be used to create these minimum depth trees $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Comment: You can add either $T_1$ as a child of $T_2$ or vice versa, giving the conceptually simpler question of whether there's a tree $T$ which uses all $N$ nodes and whose height makes the obvious bound tight. Presumably you chose to phrase it differently in order to avoid the issue that this gives the root an out-degree of $p$ where the other branches have out-degree of no more than $p-1$? I note also that $p=1$ is a special case where the answer is "Only if $k=C=1$", and $p=2$ reduces to finding a Hamiltonian path (although the underlying graph might have enough structure to make this easy).